# Disable a longpress

Tags: ios, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

How can I disable a longpress?

I have set a longpress in a viewcontroller and it's working ok but i'd like it to stop working after I press another button.

I can add a flag and set it to false after I press button B and than the long press stops workingm like this:

```
func longpress(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)  { 
   if flag = true { 
       // action 
   } 
}
```

But I think it's not the right way. SO, What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at the superclass of UILongPressGestureRecognizer, [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer).  It has a property [isEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624220-isenabled) that can be used to turn off recognition and turn it back on again.

EDIT: add example code below per poster request

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController{

        @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
        private var longPressGestureRecognizer:UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress))
            longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1
            button.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)
        }

        @objc private func longPress (longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
            if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == .began {
                print("long press began")
            }
        }

        @IBAction func tapDisableButton(_ sender: Any) {
            longPressGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = !longPressGestureRecognizer.isEnabled
            print("long press \(longPressGestureRecognizer.isEnabled ? "enabled" : "disabled")")
        }
    }
```

Comment: You beat me to it. (Voted.) It's easy to forget to check a class's superclass. Often the things you need are hidden further up the class hierarchy.

Comment: Yes but how can I set it to, let's say: UILongPress.isenable = false from inside a button? Because this UILongPress is unresolved identifier....

Comment: You need to have a reference an instance.  When you create the UILongPressGestureRecognizer, save a copy of it in a property on your view controller or if you create it in interface builder, drag out an IBOutlet.  Set isEnabled to false on that property.

Comment: I've saved a copy like this: UIlongPressGlobal = UILongPress. I defined it inside the viewcontroller class like this: let longPressGlobal = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.longpress(gestureRecognizer:))). When I set it to false it does nothing: UILongPressGlobal.isenabled = false .  (I didn't drag it on the IBOutlet)

Comment: I updated the answer.  The example code works  when I run it.  There are two buttons on the story board, one that I add the long press two that has the outlet called button and one that has the IBAction tapDisableButton.

Comment: First of all, many thanks for the help so far. Done that and I get this: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" :(

Comment: In my code I have a mapview and I am longpressing in the map to add annotation. The button should make the app to stop adding annotations (disable the long press)

Comment: The app only crashes when It goes to the "longPressRec.isEnabled = !longPressRec.isEnabled" line. But it starts  with long press disabled,,,,

Comment: your gesture recognizer is nil.  I can't tell you why without seeing your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127582/discussion-between-h-n-and-josh-homann).

Comment: I done it. I forgot to do the copy of the LongPress.... It's done now!!!